Is there a proof that a smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is traversible?
I apologize if this question is stupid, I do not have a formal education in Math`s unfortunately, however I was thinking about a problem I can't formalize properly. Also if any of my terminology is off please correct me I am eager to learn!
Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a (smooth?)-hypersurface, which can be split into regions $M_1,.., M_k$. These regions are all characterized that within their border they are concave. It can be thought of as a range of hills with the peaks being on the borders of each region. We have a function $f$, that permutes our position $x$ such that we traverse the surface. Is there a proof that if $x \in M_1$ that there $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}: f^n(x) \not\in M_1$?.
An armature surface illustration
